# Download file from unstable domain

Tags: xml

Ok, in my app, I have a file check that basically downloads a file located here: www.mydomain.com/files/myxml.xml.

It downloads it and reads it. It is needed for the app to run. The problem is that the domain is unstable and I would like to redirect it to my new domain. I no longer have the source code for that version of the software to edit the connection string and the next version of my software is still a long ways away. So is there any way to make it redirect to a new location without releasing a modified version?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking if you can redirect one page to another - is that correct?

If so, check out htaccess: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: It isn't a page, it is a file that is being downloaded by my C# app. I want it to download it from a new URL. I don't see how that article can help if the domain does goes down. The .htaccess file will not work then. Thanks, though.

Comment: Ah. I see. You could redirect the file within .htaccess to the new domain, but you're correct in saying that if won't be very helpful if the domain goes down.